# Basic WCF service gets "Invalid application path" on Test Settings

Tags: wcf, iis-7

**Caveats:**  It's been six years since I deployed a few web services and my knowledge of IIS is slim.

**Background:**  I'm trying to host a WCF 4.0 service under IIS on my local box (Win7 64-bit) but keep getting "Invalid application path" when attempting to Test Connection.  So I've gone vanilla and

1. created and started a new WCF Application (via the .NET template) (so responds under Cassini);
2. added a new application under the Default Web Site;
3. assinged it to the DefaultAppPool;
4. set the path to the folder where my .svc file resides; and
5. verified that the DefaultAppPool is targeting the 4.0 framework

Also, when I test the default web site settings pass-through authentication succeeds but an Authorization warning indicates "Cannot verify access to path (C:\inetpub\wwwroot).

**Problem:**  When I pull up the apps basic settings and click "Test Settings..." I get an error "There was an error while performing this operation.  Details:  Invalid application path"

Does anyone have suggestions as to how to get the settings to check out correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: On your step 4: is that the same folder that contains the web.config file for the site? Make sure you're pointing to the *root* folder of your application and not a subfolder containing the *.svc file.

Comment: @Cory, thanks.  It is pointing to the folder where the project template puts both the .svc and the web.config (child of the solution folder).  To narrow variables I'm using the WCF Application template with zero mods (project is child of solution, config and svc in root of project, bin dir is child of project).

Comment: Maybe you could try re-registering WCF with IIS, or let Visual Studio create the virtual directory for you by opening the Properties page for your project, then Web or Debug tab (I forget which), switch it to use IIS, enter an alias and click the "Create Virtual Directory" button. Remove your existing application from IIS first.

Comment: Thanks, again.  Still having the same issue.  I did need to register ASP.NET when creating the virtual directory so looks like some hole has been plugged, but am ultimately seeing the same failed settings test.

Comment: Have you tried a quick `iisreset` in a command window? Do you have a physical folder with the same name as your virtual directory alias in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`?

Comment: Also, try this: http://code4word.com/iis7-invalid-application-path-error

Comment: Thanks, again.  (getting pulled away)  I've tried the re-registrations and iisresets without luck.  Haven't yet gotten to the URL above.